# webviews in titanium Or native components

Tags: javascript, html, titanium

i want to design a very attractive UI in titanium " animation and complex component " ! so does titanium support HTML5 and CSS3 if yes HOW ? do i have to embed a webview in the application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using **Titanium Mobile** you can do both. You can embed HTML and CSS in webviews and you can use its' Javascript API to create scrollviews, views, textareas and the like which will be compiled to objective C.
The latter being faster of course.

**Titanium Desktop**, however seems to work slightly different. I've only started my research but by the looks of it you create your views in HTML and CSS and that's that.

I suppose it depends what you want to do.

Appcelarator have great docs and some really handy videos by the way: http://training.appcelerator.com/zero-to-app

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

if you are focused on creating you UI with HTML5 and CSS then Titanium is not the correct tool for you.

In Titanium your UI is created using **native components** the exact way you would do it using objective c

Comment: Except still 10x slower, or maybe 30x slower on Android (rough estimate)

Comment: What are you even talking about? Throwing out random comments on 2yr old posts... with no real data to support it.

Comment: I'm talking about how slow apps produced by Titanium are. It's the most frustratingly bad tool I've ever used. Also, I said it was a rough estimate :) Obviously hyperbolic. I just wanted to point out to future people looking into this post that Titanium probably isn't the right solution in general, go native if at all possible.

Comment: Thats called trolling, but thanks for the clarification from your vast years of experience.

Comment: I prefer venting but fair enough

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions, yes it supports HTML5 and CSS3, and yes, you have to use a WebView. The WebView is technically provided by the platform, but all modern devices support this.